# Python, how to keep a non-class method as non-class method?

Tags: python, function, methods

I am making a set of classes that call functions that were defined in a different module.  To know which function they must call, the function is stored as a variable of the class (or at least that was what I tried).  However, when I try to call it, it automatically assumes that the function is a class method and passes "self" as an argument, which logically causes an error because the function received too many arguments.  Do you know how can I avoid the function becoming a class method.

The code would be like:

```
# Module A
def func1(a):
    print a
def func2(a):
    print a,a

# Module B
from A import *
class Parent:
    def func():
        self.sonFunc("Hiya!")
class Son1:
    sonFunc = func1
class Son2:
    sonFunc = func2

so = Son1()
s.func()
# Should print "Hiya!"
s = Son2()
s.func()
# Should print "Hiya! Hiya!"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing is somewhat of a nonstandard/odd thing, but this should work:

```
class Son_1(object):

    son_func = staticmethod(func_1)

class Son_2(object):

    son_func = staticmethod(func_2)
```

Normally, `staticmethod` is used as a decorator, but since decorators are just syntactical sugar, you can use them this way too.

An arguably cleaner but also more advanced way would be with a `metaclass`:

```
class HasSonMeta(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):

        attrs['son_func'] = staticmethod(attrs.pop('__son_func__'))
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)


class Son1(object):

     __metaclass__ = HasSonMeta
     __son_func__ = func_1

class Son2(object):

    __metaclass__ = HasSonMeta
    __son_func__ = func_2
```

Using this form, you could also define the function directly in the class (though then it gets even more confusing to anyone reading this code):

```
class Son3(object):

    __metaclass__ = HasSonMeta

    def __son_func__():

        pass
```

While there could be a very narrow/obscure scenario where this would be an optimal implementation, you would probably be better served by putting your functions in a base class and then referring to (or overridding) them as needed in the children.

Comment: Wow, thanks.  `staticmethod` solved it perfectly.  Even though for the moment it is overkill, I loved reading about the metaclass.